# Parsing args and kwargs in decorators

Tags: python, decorator

I've got a function that takes args and kwargs, and I need to do something in my decorator based on the value of the **2nd** arg in the function, like in the code below:

```
def workaround_func():
    def decorator(fn):
        def case_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            if args[1] == 2:
                print('The second argument is a 2!')
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return case_decorator
    return decorator

@workaround_func()
def my_func(arg1, arg2, kwarg1=None):
    print('arg1: {} arg2: {}, kwargs: {}'.format(arg1, arg2, kwarg1))
```

The problem is that python allows users to call the function with the second argument as a regular argument OR a keyword-argument, so if the user calls `my_func` with `arg2` as a kwarg, it raises an `IndexError`, see below:

```
In [8]: d.my_func(1, 2, kwarg1=3)
The second argument is a 2!
arg1: 1 arg2: 2, kwargs: 3

In [9]: d.my_func(1, arg2=2, kwarg1=3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-87dc89222a9e> in <module>()
----> 1 d.my_func(1, arg2=2, kwarg1=3)

/home/camsparr/decoratorargs.py in case_decorator(*args, **kwargs)
      2     def decorator(fn):
      3         def case_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
----> 4             if args[1] == 2:
      5                 print('The second argument is a 2!')
      6             return fn(*args, **kwargs)

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Is there a way around this without just doing a `try/except` and catch the `IndexError`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found an answer using the python [`decorator`](https://github.com/micheles/decorator) package. One feature of this package is that it preserves positional/keyword args no matter how the user passes them. It has the added benefit of reducing a lot of code, so my original code:

```
def workaround_func():
    def decorator(fn):
        def case_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            if args[1] == 2:
                print('The second argument is a 2!')
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return case_decorator
    return decorator

@workaround_func()
def my_func(arg1, arg2, kwarg1=None):
    print('arg1: {} arg2: {}, kwargs: {}'.format(arg1, arg2, kwarg1))
```

becomes:

```
from decorator import decorator

@decorator
def workaround_decorator(f, *args, **kwargs):
    if args[1] == 2:
        print('The second argument is 2!')
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

@workaround_decorator
def my_func(arg1, arg2, kwarg1=None):
    print('arg1: {} arg2: {}, kwargs: {}'.format(arg1, arg2, kwarg1))
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the most robust way that I can think of to handle it... The trick is to inspect the name of the second argument.  Then, in the decorator, you check to see if that name is present in `kwargs`.  If yes, then you use that.  If no, then you use `args`.

```
from inspect import getargspec    

def decorate(fn):
    argspec = getargspec(fn)
    second_argname = argspec[0][1]
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        special_value = (kwargs[second_argname] 
                         if second_argname in kwargs else args[1])
        if special_value == 2:
            print "foo"
        else:
            print "no foo for you"
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

@decorate
def foo(a, b, c=3):
    pass

foo(1,2,3)
foo(1,b=2,c=4)
foo(1,3,5)
foo(1,b=6,c=5)
```

running this results in:

```
foo
foo
no foo for you
no foo for you
```

as expected.

Comment: in python>=3.11 `from inspect import getfullargspec` instead of `from inspect import getargspec`