# How to only process *args and **kwargs in decorator and leave other arguments untouched

Tags: python-3.x, decorator, args, keyword-argument

I want to have a decorator, that takes only `*args` and `**kwargs` as input, makes some changes to them and then call the original function with positional and named arguments from the decorated function unchanged.

The change to the arguments is just to prepend `--` to the `args` and also to the keys of the `dict` of `kwargs`.

E.g. I want to use this decorator like this:

```
from decorator import decorator

@decorator
def prepare_opts(decorated_func, *args, **kwargs):
    prepared_args = prepare_single_opt_keys(args)
    prepared_kwargs = prepare_named_opt_keys(kwargs)

    return decorated_func(*prepared_args, **prepared_kwargs)

@my_decorator
def func1(pos1, pos2, *args, named1=None, **kwargs):
    ...do stuff
```

Here `pos1`, `pos2` and `named1` should be ignored by the decorator.

So a call to `func1` like this:

```
func1('foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', named1='foobar', foo='bar')
```

Should call the decorated function like this:

```
func1('foo', 'bar', named1='foobar', ('--foo', '--bar'), {'--foo': 'bar'})
```

But this can obviously not work, as the decorator passes `('--foo', '--bar', '--foo', '--bar')` to `pos1` and `{'--named1': 'foobar', '--foo': 'bar'}` to `pos2`.

I know that I can get the correct arguments if I change the decorator to:

```
@decorator
def prepare_opts(decorated_func, pos1, pos2, *args, named1, **kwargs):
    prepared_args = prepare_single_opt_keys(args)
    prepared_kwargs = prepare_named_opt_keys(kwargs)

    return decorated_func(pos1, pos2, *prepared_args, named1, **prepared_kwargs)
```

But the problem here is, I want the decorator to work with a lot of different functions, that all have a different number of positional and named parameters and additional `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Summary of my question: **Is there a way to parse `*args` and `**kwargs` in a decorator without touching any of the positional and named arguments of the decorated function and without consuming those in the `*args`/`**kwargs`-Arguments of my Decoratorfunction?**

Comment: I haven't really delved into whether these ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147816/preserving-signatures-of-decorated-functions), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906760/parsing-args-and-kwargs-in-decorators)) contain the exact solution to your problem, but at the very least they are related and could provide some valuable insights. In particular, it's worth at least checking out the [`decorator`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [inspect.getargspec](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) function. I didn't test it but you can use this approach.

```
import inspect

def your_decorator(func):
    func_args = inspect.getargspec(func)[0]
    args_number = len(func_args)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > args_number:
            args[args_number:] = prepare_single_opt_keys(args[args_number:])
        optional_kwargs = {k: kwargs.pop(k) for k in kwargs if k not in func_args}
        prepared_kwargs = prepare_named_opt_keys(optional_kwargs)
        kwargs.update(prepared_kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

But I am pretty sure that you don't need it. This kind of introspection should and can be almost always avoided.

Comment: A slightly adjusted version of this worked for me. I still wait 1-2 days if there is another "best practice" to do this as you say it can be almost always avoided to use introspection. If no better idea pops up, I gonna accept your answer and add the changes I made to make it work with python3

Comment: From the inspect package  getargspec: `This function is deprecated, as it does not support annotations or
    keyword-only parameters and will raise ValueError if either is present
    on the supplied callable.`